# SFML Inputs Skipped

Tags: c++, input, game-development, sfml

I built this game and I feel like it works ok now, but sometimes it seems to skip inputs, and sometimes when i didn't let one key go yet, and press another one, it doesn't register that. For some keys it works tho, I guess that's because of the order I wrote it in the input function? How can I check for multiple keydownpresses, instead of having to wait for the one before to be lifted up again?

Also I'm happy for any feedback on the structure of my code which is why I will post the whole thing, it's my first ""big"" SFML program and I'm happy to learn how to structure it well and how to increase readability + good practices. I especially feel like my *update()* function is a bit useless and at the wrong place doing the wrong things, and also I don't know if I put too much functionality in the *input()* function, as that's where I am assigning all the coordinates for the head and each body part, but for now everything works.

My code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

// constants
const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1024;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 512;
const int FRAMERATE_LIMIT = 8;
const int GRID_SCALE = 32;

// enum
enum Direction {
    UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, NONE
};

// struct
struct Snake {
    sf::RectangleShape head;
    std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> body;
};

class Game {
    private:
        // movement vectors for each direction
        const sf::Vector2f UP_VECTOR    = sf::Vector2f(0,-GRID_SCALE);
        const sf::Vector2f DOWN_VECTOR  = sf::Vector2f(0, GRID_SCALE);
        const sf::Vector2f LEFT_VECTOR  = sf::Vector2f(-GRID_SCALE, 0);
        const sf::Vector2f RIGHT_VECTOR = sf::Vector2f(GRID_SCALE, 0);

    public:
        // attributes
        sf::RenderWindow window;
        struct Snake snake;
        Direction direction;
        sf::RectangleShape apple;
        std::vector<sf::Vector2f> snake_coordinates;

        // method
        void init() {
            window.create(sf::VideoMode(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), "My window");
            window.setFramerateLimit(FRAMERATE_LIMIT);
            snake.head.setSize(sf::Vector2f(GRID_SCALE,GRID_SCALE));
            snake.head.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
            snake.head.setPosition(WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2);
            snake.body = {snake.head};
            snake.body[0].setPosition(WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2);
            snake.body[0].move(-GRID_SCALE,0);
            direction = RIGHT; // ohne das fängts irwie an nach oben zu laufen kp, kinda hacky
            draw_apple();
        }

        // method
        void input() {
            // maybe find a better place for this?
            // need to reset the snake_coordinates vector for collision detection with itself somewhere
            snake_coordinates = {};

            sf::Event event;
            while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
                if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
            }

            // WENN MAN STATT ELSE IF NUR IF NIMMT, KANN MAN AUCH DIAGONAL LAUFEN
            if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)      && direction != LEFT)
                direction = RIGHT;
            else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)  && direction != RIGHT)
                direction = LEFT;
            else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)    && direction != DOWN)
                direction = UP;
            else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)  && direction != UP)
                direction = DOWN;
        
            // set new snake.head_pos 
            sf::Vector2f temp_pos = snake.head.getPosition();
            snake.head.move(getDirectionVector(direction));

            // set new snake.body_pos
            // also used to build list of snake.body coordinates, so that i can check the snake - snake collision later
            // iterativ die snake.body_parts coordinates setten
            sf::Vector2f current_pos;
            snake_coordinates.push_back(current_pos);
            for(int i = 0; i < snake.body.size(); i++) {
                current_pos = snake.body[i].getPosition();
                snake.body[i].setPosition(temp_pos);
                snake_coordinates.push_back(current_pos);
                temp_pos = current_pos;
            }
        }

        // method
        void update() {
            collision_detection();
        }

        // method
        void draw() {
            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
            window.draw(apple);
            window.draw(snake.head);
            for(sf::RectangleShape body_part : snake.body) {
                window.draw(body_part);
            }
        }

        // method
        void display() {
            window.display();
        }   

        
        // return direction vectors
        sf::Vector2f getDirectionVector(Direction& direction) {
            switch(direction) {
                case UP:
                    return UP_VECTOR;
                case DOWN:
                    return DOWN_VECTOR;    
                case LEFT:
                    return LEFT_VECTOR;
                case RIGHT:
                    return RIGHT_VECTOR;
                default:
                    return sf::Vector2f(0,0);
            }
        }

        // generate apple
        void draw_apple() {
            apple.setSize(sf::Vector2f(GRID_SCALE,GRID_SCALE));
            apple.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
            // set next apple to random position (chatGPT copy/paste)
            apple.setPosition(rand() % (WINDOW_WIDTH / GRID_SCALE) * GRID_SCALE, rand() % (WINDOW_HEIGHT / GRID_SCALE) * GRID_SCALE);
        }

        // check for collisions
        void collision_detection() {
            sf::Vector2f snake_head_position = snake.head.getPosition();
            sf::Vector2f apple_position = apple.getPosition();
            
            // apple - snake.head
            //if(snake.head_position.x == apple_position.x && snake.head_position.y == apple_position.y) {
            if(snake_head_position == apple_position) {
                draw_apple();
                snake.body.push_back(snake.head);
            }

            // snake.head - border
            if(snake_head_position.x < 0 || snake_head_position.x > WINDOW_WIDTH - GRID_SCALE || snake_head_position.y < 0 || snake_head_position.y > WINDOW_HEIGHT - GRID_SCALE)
                window.close();

            // snake - snake
            for(sf::Vector2f current_coord : snake_coordinates) {
                if(current_coord == snake.head.getPosition()) {
                    window.close();
                }
            }
        }
};


int main() {
    Game game;
    game.init();
    while(game.window.isOpen()) {
        game.input();
        game.update();
        game.draw();
        game.display();
    }

    return 0;
}type here
```

You can compile the code on Linux easily with

```
g++ snake.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

and run with

```
./a.out
```

if you have SFML installed, like this

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev
```

(I don't know why I added this, it seems as if people who can help me know how to compile and install SFML/have SFML already installed)

I tried using if and else if statements which at least blocked diagonal movement from happening, and i tried a switch statement which was super weird, now I don't have a lot of ideas.

Comment: I wouldn't use `else if` when polling input. You most likely do not want mutual exclusion but you will need to figure out what it means for multiple keys to be down at once. You might also want to handle the `KeyPressed` event instead of polling to check if keys are down. Then you can handle input in the order it happened. https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/window-events.php I don't know if KeyReleased is important to you or not.

Comment: I'd suggest reacting to keyboard events instead of using `sf::keyboard::isKeyPressed` - then you won't miss any key presses or key releases. As it is now you'll miss anything that happens between two calls of the function.

Comment: Note that many real physical keyboards [don’t support](https://www.renoise.com/blog/crippled-chords-without-full-n-key-rollover) arbitrary chords.